# Rows inside of a container obscured at the top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have come across a problem whereby if I add rows to an overflow container some of the rows at the top are obscured. My real application is a bit more complicated than this in that it also adds things inside of the row, and if you pick a "wrong" option, then the top row gets hidden completely.

Is it possible to fit all of the rows inside of the container, so that when you scroll all the way to the top, you can always see the topmost row? Currently, depending on how many rows you have, a portion, or whole top row is hidden.

JsFiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/nazariyv/okwpesgq/6/).

And also code here:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let addBtn = document.getElementById("addRow");
  addBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
    let newRow = "<div class='row'></div>"
    wrapper.innerHTML += newRow;
  })
};
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40vh;
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.row {
  display: block;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="wrapper">

      <div class="row"></div>
      <div class="row"></div>
      <div class="row"></div>
      <div class="row"></div>
      <div class="row"></div>
      <div class="row"></div>
      <div class="row"></div>
      <div class="row"></div>
      <div class="row"></div>

    </div>

    <div>
      <button id="addRow">Add</button>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: does the wrapper need to be flex?

Comment: is flex the problem, why? Not really, if I can have centered rows and vertically oriented.

Comment: Just add margin 10px auto to the rows and they will be centered without flex.  Otherwise you have to have a set flex-basis in order for overflow to work properly with flex - which I'm guessing you don't want as you use a min-height.  Have a google for flex not working properly with overflow - there are a few answers that may help you understand why your solution doesn't work properly

Comment: Made it work with your suggestion. I have never used flex-basis, but the rows have set height, and I think flex-basis specifies how they would grow/shrink? A solution of turning the wrapper into block works very well. Thanks

Comment: Also works! Wow. So what is the issue with `justify-content: center`, in this case? Thanks

Comment: it align content vertically at the middle of parents container. 
so that what you see is only the button half of rows, the top half  is hidden above the wrappaer. you can inspect this to check it

Comment: Lesson learned. Thanks!

Comment: welcome, I've added this as a solution so that anyone with same problem can found the answer easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `align-item: center` from `#wrapper`.

The problem is this property align all children rows in the middle of parent `#wrapper`.

So if you count the rows it's just the half of rows that should be appeared.

Try to inspect it, half of rows are above #wrapper which can't be viewed.

you can also have some padding to `#wrapper` to have some color below the last row.

check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o5sdvq08/)

Answer (score 0):

Updated fiddle with the solution - https://jsfiddle.net/zL61c84x/

```
#wrapper {

  height: 40vh;
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#wrapperInner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```